# Why my validation does not pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, grails-validation

I am developing Rails 3 app.

I would like to validate the "**Cake**" model's "**size**" attribute input field to only allow user to input **+1,-1,+10,-10** and **+25,-25**, nothing else.

I use the following validation to validate "size":

```
class Cake < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :size, :with => /^[-+]?(1|10|25)$/, :message=>'size not allowed.'
  ...

end
```

(The "size" attribute in my database "cakes" table is a "**double**" type.)

In the UI, I always get fail message of the validation even I input 1 or 10 or 25 or +1 or whatever. Why my validation does not pass even the value is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if validating an Integer with a Regex works.

You could try `validates_inclusion_of :size, :in=>[-1,+1,-10,+10,-25,+25], :message=>'size not allowed.'`